Logging MongoDb queries for debugging
Log the MongoDb queries that are executed based on the business logic into console or log file.
ASP.NET Core, Mongo client, Mongo DB, LINQ.
I want this to understand how my queries are translated and executed in MongoDB. This will help fix performance issues, if any.

Have you looked at database auditing?

What did you try to achieve your goal? Did you try to google it up? If yes, what have you found so far?

Did you use any ORM package inside your project to query the database? If you have, which one?

See my answer here. In 2 words, you can subscribe on driver events, in particular CommandStartedEvent will contain information about sent commands to the server.
Also, you can use query analyzer plugin for the driver that will allow you to see queries that will be sent to the server just in VS notes:

As additional approach, there is an option to use ILogger impls, you can find details here
